# Target element that's appear on a custom viewport like a div or ul

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this plugin [Viewport Selectors for jQuery](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport), here is the source:

```
(function($) {

$.belowthefold = function(element, settings) {
    var fold = $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop();
    return fold <= $(element).offset().top - settings.threshold;
};

$.abovethetop = function(element, settings) {
    var top = $(window).scrollTop();
    return top >= $(element).offset().top + $(element).height() - settings.threshold;
};

$.rightofscreen = function(element, settings) {
    var fold = $(window).width() + $(window).scrollLeft();
    return fold <= $(element).offset().left - settings.threshold;
};

$.leftofscreen = function(element, settings) {
    var left = $(window).scrollLeft();
    return left >= $(element).offset().left + $(element).width() - settings.threshold;
};

$.inviewport = function(element, settings) {
    return !$.rightofscreen(element, settings) && !$.leftofscreen(element, settings) && !$.belowthefold(element, settings) && !$.abovethetop(element, settings);
};

$.extend($.expr[':'], {
    "below-the-fold": function(a, i, m) {
        return $.belowthefold(a, {threshold : 0});
    },
    "above-the-top": function(a, i, m) {
        return $.abovethetop(a, {threshold : 0});
    },
    "left-of-screen": function(a, i, m) {
        return $.leftofscreen(a, {threshold : 0});
    },
    "right-of-screen": function(a, i, m) {
        return $.rightofscreen(a, {threshold : 0});
    },
    "in-viewport": function(a, i, m) {
        return $.inviewport(a, {threshold : 0});
    }
});


})(jQuery);
```

I want to use this plugin on a scrollable div or ul not on the window.

If I change the selector `$(window)` to anything else, everything worked perfectly.

How can I make it custom, for example something like this:

```
$('ul li').inVeiwPort({viewPort:$('ul')}).css('background-color','red');
```

Answer (score 0):

This part:

```
$.extend($.expr[':'].....
```

Creates  custom pseudo selectors so you can do:

```
$('ul li:in-viewport').css('background-color','red');
```

Or maybe better

```
$('ul:in-viewport li:in-viewport').css('background-color','red');
```

I've never used this plugin so play around with variations to see what works best for you

Comment: thanks sir. this how it works but i need something else
here in your example `$('ul:in-viewport li:in-viewport')` this `:in-viewport` pseudo selector it refer to window object `$(window)`...  i have an `ul` with custom height and it's overflow is scroll-able i want to target what is appear on it what is actually on the `ul` port only not what is appear on the whole screen

Comment: Make another version of the plugin that lets you do the same thing with elements

Comment: how can i !?
i need some help